# How to send a pop up message from a Mac to Windows on same network?

Tags: windows

I want to use the equivalent of `net send`, but from a MacBook.
I want to send a pop up message from my mac to a windows machine on same network. Is smbutil the command to use?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command, then enter your message and press ⌃D to finish and send.

```
smbclient -M NETBIOSNAME -U FROMNAME
```

<sup>`-U FROMNAME` is optional</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I forgot to mention the version, 10.9.4, and smbclient is no longer available...

Comment: Does this work without doing any configuration in a Windows machine? Or do I need to do something in the windows machine beforehand, like installing samba and/or launching the server?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe for others who find the question:

But it's no pop up!
It's more like a chat.

One machine has to be the Server:

```
nc -v -l 12345
```

`-v`: verbose (more information about execution of the command)

`12345`: any port of your choice higher than 1024

All other machines can be client(s):

```
nc -v [ip of server] 12345
```

`-v`: look above

`[ip of server]` to find out ip: ìfconfig | grep inet`(probably one of the 192.168.xxx.xxx or maybe even 172.xxx.xxx.xxx numbers)

`12345`: again the chosen port of the server

Hope that helps!